# How to get text from a <td> using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I try to get the text from an html looking like this:

```
</td><td align='center'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'>0.1200</td><td align='left'><img
```

I'm interested in getting the number "0.1200".

My code is this:

```
`url = "http://...."
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('td', {'align': 'right'}):
    for row in link.find_next_sibling("td"):
        print(row)
```

I get an error message "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".
Any sugestions on fixing the problem?

Comment: for which loop iterator are you getting the NoneType error?

Comment: @theBrainyGeek for the second one

Comment: Please don't add solved to title, instead pass or accept answers that worked for you, to learn more see [tour]

Comment: @PetterFriberg I am truly sorry, I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this out please? (It is hard to help you out if you don't give us the URL)

Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('td', {'align': 'right'}):
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem and gave me the exact output I wanted!